# Oracle Linux server boot failure

Tags: linux, boot, boot-loader

I have an Oracle Linux 6.9 server which crashed and now it is failing to boot with the following error.

> Boot Failed - Hard Disk 0: Fv (CDxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx) / FvFiles(1Fxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-9-xxxx)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun Sasidharan

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

Here are the steps :

1. Boot from Centos 6 CD to Rescue mode
2. `chroot /mnt/sysimage`
3. Confirmed that OS is booted in EFI mode (command - `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"` )
4. Find EFI boot partition - `df /boot/efi` In my case it is /dev/sdk1
5. Confirm that "/dev/sdk1" has boot flag set, using command `parted /dev/sdk print`
6. Use `efibootmgr -v` to view your UEFI boot entries. In my case it is missing an entry to "Oracle Linux"
7. Created a new boot entry for my OS using `efibootmgr --create --label "Oracle Linux Server 6" --disk /dev/sdk --part 1 --loader "\EFI\redhat\grub.efi"`
8. Reboot the server and it successfully booted from Oracle Linux!

Comment: The partition boot flag is not used in UEFI boot. This is a not necessary step.